# Are there conventions to writing a --help message?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-interface

I'm writing my first real shell script and I want to put in a proper `--help` message. Looking at various command line programs, I see at least some sort of pattern:

```
$ command --help
Usage: command [OPTION] [FILE]
Performs some action to a file.

-x  changes the command in some way
-y  changes the command in a different way
```

Is this written down anywhere or is this just an informal convention?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with much (most) stuff in UNIX, this is purely a tradition. Programmers find these kinds of `--help` messages useful, so they try to imitate the `--help` messages that they find most useful, and the tradition is born. It is a bit unfortunate for people that have their first encounter with UNIX that it usually takes some time for these traditions to be codified in some way, there is simply no comprehensive source for this kind of stuff.

So, just do a shameless copy of everything you find usefull about the `--help` messages that you know and add the stuff that you find helpful. Do the same thing wherever you can, and you will be as true to the UNIX tradition as you can be...